# Have the element who call my js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know my question have answer in the past but I don't have the vocabulary to find this.

I call a JavaScript function like this:

```
<a href="javascript:showTable('.stats-table');">Voir +</a>
```

This function change the state of the element `.stats-table` but I want to know which button have been clicked to call this function?

Better : can I have a jQuery object of this button?

Comment: Very nice [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/)

Comment: One can use `e.sender();`

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the `this` reference to know which button was clicked,

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:showTable('.stats-table',this);">Voir +</a>
```

JS:

```
function showTable(selec,elem){
 var currentElem = $(elem); //Clicked element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery, you might consider refactor your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.show-table-link').on('click', function(){
    var $usedButton = $(this)
    showTable('.stats-table')
  }
})


<a href="#show-table" class="show-table-link">Voir +</a>
```

It's good practice to attach the on click handler instead of writing it inline. Further reading [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and [jQuery event basics](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).

Comment: Don't you want to put `$usedButton` as the second argument to `showTable`? And shouldn't it be `this` and not `$(this)`?

Comment: You could have used `.data()` to store that selector instead of hard coding it in the JS. It would be better and cleaner. :)

Comment: You could add the $usedButton as an argument, depending on what you gonna do with it. If you'll like to hide the link or change the text of the link after showing the table, you might as well do it in the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is like this:

```
function showTable(selec) {
   // some code
}
```

You can get the clicked element like this, using `this`:

```
function showTable(selec) {
   // some code
   var clickedElem = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the signature of the function and the way you invoke it (as others have suggested), you can use the global `window.event` to identify the clicked element:

```
function showTable(selector)
{
     var clickedElement = window.event.target;

     //...
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any value or id and your can identify the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTable(clss_name,fun_id)
    {
     if(fun_id=='A1')
     {
      alert("First function Executed");
     }
     if(fun_id=='A2')
     {
      alert("Second Function is executed");
     }
    }
    </script>
    ......
    ......
    ......

    <a href="javascript:showTable('.stats-table',this.id);" id="A1">Voir +</a>
    <a href="javascript:showTable('.stats-table',this.id);" id="A2">Voir2 +</a>
```